# SET sentencia preparada mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

¿Cual es forma correcta de realizar la siguiente consulta?

Tengo una función a la cual le quiero asignar una serie, si ésta la ejecuto directo en el motor genera el `div` concatenado, pero en el `PHP` arroja un error. Si la declaro fuera y lo asigno por una variable arroja un `NULL`.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SET @serie=0; 
            SELECT DISTINCT id_semana, 
            CONCAT('Semana ', id_semana, ' - ', tramo) AS semana, 
            CONCAT('div_', @serie:=@serie+1) AS div_
            FROM ab_route, ab_mandante
            WHERE ab_route.id_mandante = ab_mandante.id and ab_route.id_mandante = 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás buscando es ejecutar múltiples consultas a la base de datos. Para lograr eso puedes utilizar [`mysqli->multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php). Pero considera la nota al final:

> *Sentencias preparadas*
>
> El uso de sentencias múltiples con sentencias preparadas no está soportado.

Por lo cual no podrás ejecutar este query utilizando `mysqli->prepare`.

A parte de esta solución, te propongo dos más:

1. Basado en [este tutorial](http://jimmod.com/blog/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/) para obtener el número de fila, puedes cambiar tu query para que luzca de esta manera:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT id_semana, 
   CONCAT('Semana ', id_semana, ' - ', tramo) AS semana, 
   CONCAT('div_', @serie:=@serie+1) AS div_,
   (SELECT @serie:=0) AS no_me_selecciones
   FROM ab_route, ab_mandante
   WHERE ab_route.id_mandante = ab_mandante.id and ab_route.id_mandante = ?
   ```

   Y así solo ejecutas 1 query.
2. Lo que buscas hacer me parece que no es apropiado que se ejecute directamente en base de datos. Puesto que vas a iterar sobre los resultados del query, puedes declarar una variable `$serie` a nivel de PHP que sea el contador y lograr el resultado allí mismo.

Comment: Realice una modificación en la función {$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SET @a = 0;");
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT id_semana, 
    tramo,
    CONCAT('Semana ', id_semana, ' - ', tramo) AS semana, 
    CONCAT('chart_div_', @a:=@a+1) AS chart_div
    FROM ".$db_table_prefix."route, ".$db_table_prefix."mandante
    WHERE ab_route.id_mandante = ab_mandante.id and ab_route.id_mandante = ?
    ");
 
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $idmandante);
 $stmt->execute();}

Comment: Lo único que has hecho es ejecutar los queries por separado. Eso también funciona. Acá igual dejo más alternativas para resolverlo.

Comment: Así es! Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Realice una modificación en la función, la declaración del set queda fuera del select de esta manera logre recuperar el array completo.
Quedando así:

```
function fetchRoute_chart($idmandante)
{
  global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SET @a = 0;");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT id_semana, 
            tramo,
            CONCAT('Semana ', id_semana, ' - ', tramo) AS semana, 
            CONCAT('chart_div_', @a:=@a+1) AS chart_div
            FROM ".$db_table_prefix."route, ".$db_table_prefix."mandante
            WHERE ab_route.id_mandante = ab_mandante.id and ab_route.id_mandante = ?
            ");

  $stmt->bind_param("i", $idmandante);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($id_semana, $tramo, $semana, $chart_div);
  while ($stmt->fetch()){
    $row[] = array('id_semana'=>$id_semana, 'tramo' => $tramo, 'semana' => $semana, 'chart_div' => $chart_div);
  }
  $stmt->close();
  return ($row);
}
```

Funciona para lo que necesito!

Comment: Ten en cuenta que ejecutar 2 queries contra la base de datos tiene un impacto de performance a diferencia de ejecutar 1 solo. Aunque para este caso parece que el impacto será muy pequeño y no se notará.